# how to combine 2 mysql rows and get one row

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, self-join

I have a table `report_card` and,

Sample data as below.

```
report_id  orig_id   test_id        name     address
------------------------------------------------------
1           JH06E     IN2001         xyz      delhi
2           HL789     IN2001         abc      mumbai
3           ZPYNR     IN2002         pqr      mumbai
4           5R4HJ     IN2002         mno      delhi
```

and I want result like to get all the rows of mumbai but address is delhi instead of mumbai ? 
here I have id 1 and 2 have same test_id and 3 and 4 have also. Output like below,

```
report_id  orig_id   test_id        name     address
------------------------------------------------------
 2           HL789     IN2001         abc      delhi
 3           ZPYNR     IN2002         pqr      delhi
```

Comment: Take a look at the self-join tag. You might be able to answer this yourself.

Comment: if test_id are same i want to pick the row where `address` is `delhi` but orig_id belongs to `mumbai` of same test_id. and thanks to quick reply...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A self join like:

```
SELECT t1.report_id, t1.orig_id, t1.test_id, t1.name, t2.address
FROM report_card t1
JOIN report_card t2
  ON t1.test_id = t2.test_id
WHERE
  t1.address = 'mumbai' AND
  t2.address = 'delhi'
```

Comment: hello @danblack, can you guide here me once again if i only want to get rows of 2 and 3 where address is `mumbai` but change it by **delhi**.

Comment: fairly easy change.

Answer (score 2):

What @danblack have written is correct, but to select the `orig_id` of mumbai you need to write your select like following.

```
SELECT t1.report_id, 
       t2.orig_id, 
       t1.test_id, 
       t1.name, 
       t1.address 
FROM   mytable t1 
       INNER JOIN mytable t2 
               ON t1.test_id = t2.test_id 
WHERE  t1.address = 'delhi' 
       AND t2.address = 'mumbai'
```

**Edit** :

> sorry here i change my result on question, can i get all the rows of
>   mumbai but address is delhi instead of mumbai

You can also do it using subquery like following.

```
SELECT t1.report_id, 
       t1.orig_id, 
       t1.test_id, 
       t1.name, 
       (SELECT address 
        FROM   mytable m 
        WHERE  m.test_id = t1.test_id 
               AND m.address = 'delhi' 
        LIMIT  1)AS address 
FROM   mytable t1 
WHERE  t1.address = 'mumbai'
```

But looking at your data and the expected result, you just need like following

```
SELECT t1.report_id, 
       t1.orig_id, 
       t1.test_id, 
       t1.name, 
       'delhi' address 
FROM   mytable t1 
WHERE  t1.address = 'mumbai'
```

Comment: sorry here i change my result on question, can i get all the rows of mumbai but address is delhi instead of mumbai ?

Comment: For that you can simply do by subquery without self join

Comment: You can have a look to updated answer for your new query.